# How to make the service to get owner profile detail in angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am very new to JSON and Angular 8.

Assume that I have created the list of owners, now I click on one owner of the company in order to see his profile.

**How can I make the service in Angular 8 to get his data using JSON.**

MY TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { CompaniesContentService } from 'src/app/home/companies-content.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-innovator-detail',
    templateUrl: './innovator-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./innovator-detail.component.scss'],
})

export class OwnerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    OwnerId: any;
    selectedOwner: any;
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private contentService: CompaniesContentService
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
            let id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
            this.ownerId = id;
        });
        this.selectedOwner = this.contentService.getOwner(this.ownerId);
    }
}
```

In companiesContentService:

```
  getOwner(id: number) {
    this.companyContent.data.forEach((company) => {
      company.owner.forEach((owner) => {
        if (owner.id === id) {
          console.log('New D :', owner)
          return { ...owner}
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

My HTML code:

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let owner of selectedOwner">
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-item class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
            <ion-label>
                {{selectedOwner.name}}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-icon name="information-circle" slot="end" color="medium"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-card>
    <img src="../../assets/imgs/sergey-brin.webp">
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle></ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Owner name here</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content class="ion-text-justify">
        Owner desc here
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I have created a JSON file like this:

```
{
"data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company one",
        "desc": "Comany Description",
        "icon": "iconPath",
        "logo": "logoPath",
        "country": "PK",
        "owners": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mr Riaz",
                "label": "owner",
                "desc": "Owner Desc here",
                "imgUrl": "imgPath"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Mr Zain",
                "label": "owner",
                "desc": "Owner Desc here",
                "imgUrl": "imgPath"
            }

        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Company two",
        "desc": "Comany Description",
        "icon": "iconPath",
        "logo": "logoPath",
        "country": "UAE",
        "Owners": [{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Mr Yasir",
            "label": "owner",
            "desc": "Owner Desc here",
            "imgUrl": "imgPath"
        }]
    }
]
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your HTML and Ts file code.

Comment: Hi @Najam I have update question now with codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the selected owner's name in the JSON data you have and show the details.

> **app.component.ts**

```
  ownersList = ["Mr Riaz", "Mr Zain", "Mr Yasir"];
  selectedOwner = "";
  selectedOwnerDetails = { id: 0, name: "", label: "", desc: "", imgUrl:""};
      
 changeHandler() {
            console.log(this.selectedOwner);
            this.ownersData.forEach((company)=>{
              company.owners.forEach((owner)=>{
                if(owner.name === this.selectedOwner){
                  this.selectedOwnerDetails = {...owner};
                }
              })
            })
          }
```

> **app.component.html**

```
<label for="owner">Owners:</label>

<select name="owners" id="owner"  [(ngModel)]="selectedOwner" (change)="changeHandler()">
  <option *ngFor="let owner of ownersList" value={{owner}}>{{owner}}</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<u>Select Owner's details</u>
<br><br>
Id : {{selectedOwnerDetails.id}}<br>
Name : {{selectedOwnerDetails.name}}<br>
Label : {{selectedOwnerDetails.label}}<br>
Desc : {{selectedOwnerDetails.desc}}<br>
ImgUrl : {{selectedOwnerDetails.imgUrl}}<br>
```

**For more details refer here :** [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzhrep?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks! @HimanshuSingh your logic works for me to get a selected owner in a service console perfectly but I am stuck to get it from a service to the component. I want the selected owner in another component (ex. owner-detail.component) where It shows selected owner is undefined. Plz help.